# recursive horner scheme java

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to program a recursive horner sheme.
At the moment it outputs the correct numbers, but in the wrong order (reversed).
However the output shall be onwards.
Any hints?

```java
public class uhs {
    public static void main (String[] args) {

        int z = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int q = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        hornerUmkehrungRekursiv(z, q);
        System.out.println("");
    }

    static int hornerUmkehrungRekursiv(int z, int q) {
        if (z == 0) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            System.out.print(z % q);
            return (hornerUmkehrungRekursiv(z / q, q) * 2) + z % q;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you add an example of the command line arguments you are passing

Comment: Z: decimal number to be converted

Comment: q = base to which q shall be converted

Comment: Example if the command line : java uhs 210 2. My required answers in this example is 11010010 but the program gives me the output 01001011

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You cannot use a StringBuilder variable, then You need to change Your code so that it makes recursive calls untill the last division, and then it prints the remainders. You just need to change Your code a bit, here is an example of how it can be done:

```
public class uhs {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int z = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int q = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        System.out.println(hornerUmkehrungRekursiv(z, q));
    }

    static int hornerUmkehrungRekursiv(int z, int q) {
        if (z / q != 0) {
            System.out.print(hornerUmkehrungRekursiv(z / q, q));
        }
        return z % q;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) but in the exercise we have given the you shouldn't use a variable which stock the result of the program. Any idea how to program it without the variable which stock the string?

Comment: Thank you for your answer and solution. Now it works how it should :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute print after the recursive call:

```
static int hornerUmkehrungRekursiv(int z, int q) {
    if (z == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        int v = z % q;
        int r = (hornerUmkehrungRekursiv(z / q, q) * 2) + v;
        System.out.print(v);
        return r;
    }
}
```

that gives you the expected result "11010010".